# Kubernetes OutOfcpu error when Requests.cpu == Limits.cpu

Tags: centos, docker, cgroups, cpu-usage, kubernetes

I'm running Kubernetes `Jobs` in which I set limits and requests both to the same number of CPUs. In some of these jobs I'm occasionally seeing `OutOfcpu` errors

When I `kubectl describe pods PODNAME` I see the following message:

```
Pod Node didn't have enough resource: cpu, requested: 8000, used: 11453, capacity: 16000
```

That pretty clearly indicates why the `OutOfcpu` occurred.

But my `Limits.cpu == Requests.cpu == 8`.

```
    Limits:
      cpu:                8
      ephemeral-storage:  500Gi
      memory:             10Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:                8
      ephemeral-storage:  300Gi
      memory:             2Gi
```

So as far as I understand I should have been throttled at 8 CPUs and fenced off from the node running out of CPU resources for the pod.

I've only noticed this recently, our Kubernetes version is 1.22.5 as of a reasonably recent upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue with a long thread about this bug.

It is introduced in k8s v 1.22 and seems a race condition which can occur when pods get scheduled on a node where another pod is terminated. The terminated pod isn't seen by the scheduler anymore, but still uses resources of the node (cpu, memory).

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/106884